# Engine stalls out when I top off my jeep with gas

Tags: jeep, fuel-tank

When I top off my gas (till the pump shuts off) fuel spurts out. It also wants to stall out when I turn it on. It happens more if I fill it up from empty, but still  happens when I fill it from half a tank, which is what I usually do. I use the same grade every time on my 2005 Jeep Wrangler TJ with 4.0 liter L6 (I6)

Answer (score 4):

With the filler neck is a fuel breather pipe which allows the tank to vent air otherwise trapped when the fuel level is topped up.  It may be that a breather pipe has become blocked.  This can mean that fuel in the tank is effectively being held in a slight vacuum making the fuel pumps job harder and starving the engine.

One good way to check this is, if the vehicle stalls (or near stalls), quickly remove the fuel cap and listen for a hissing of air rushing across the neck of the fuel tank.

Comment: I had a car on which the fuel breather pipe had come loose, so it was lower than its original position. This had the effect of gas spurting out while filling up.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you have an air lock. (Don't hold me to it.)